# Form search save in file & display result

Tags: php, forms

What is the most elegant and efficient way of search a string against injected script file in PHP.

## **The flow:**

i want make form search when user input strings & click search, data searched save on txt/php file with auto create new file based on month & year ex: **-201601.php / txt**

1. then data was saved on safety query with **serial key** on each string
2. then if data on -201601.php contents have more than 1000+ query, the data old was **deleted** automatic
3. then how showing **50 strings** based on **random** strings on -201601.php
4. then in -201601.php there are no **double** string or same string

*If you have a solution for my issue and want to post an answer, please add some explanation so that I can understand why/how you did it so that I won't come asking the same questions all over again. Thanks*

Im search & create file that i want making it with my plot imagination. Here is what I have so far manually :

---

```
<center>
<form action="./cari.php?q=" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder=" Cari .." style="cursor: pointer;width:69%"/> 
 <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
</center><?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $data = ''.$_GET['q']."<br>\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('rcnt.php', htmlspecialchars($data), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        //echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
//else {die('no post data to process');}
?>
```

Im stuck searching with cant find related tutorial & hope find answer :(

Please your help, i want learn more with this, i use XAMPP 5.6

Comment: What happens currently? I'd think that `./cari.php?q=` as the action and having a name attribute with the same value would cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

First step, the ?q= var the browser will create, you don`t need to set this on your form action.

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search">
</form>
```

The PHP code will be:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET["q"]))
{
   $file = fopen(date("Ym") . ".txt","a+");
   fwrite($file, $_GET["q"] . "\r\n"); //\r\n jump the line
   flose($file);
}
?>
```

If today is the 1st search of the 1st day of the month, the file will not exists, then, the PHP will create it, otherwise, will open and write on it.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I update my format post. 
Thank you before Mr.Thiago for answer. yes there are create file automate based on year month.
Now how to delete old string if have maximum srings reached?

Answer (score 1):

We could try this way:

```
<?php

$theFile = date("Ym") . ".txt";

$myFile = file($theFile);

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){ //deleting the first 100 lines
    unset($myFile[$i]);
}

//rewriting the file without the 100st first lines

file_put_contents($theFile, implode($myFile));

?>
```

Comment: cool youre so cool, that work.. btw im sorry cant give upvote for now cause "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score" :(

Comment: I understand you, don't worry. See you!

Comment: <3 :D Btw Mr.Thiago how about force input double query in 201601.php ? is this possible when im input in form ? #sorrymybadenglish

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand the case.

Comment: i have url like this http://localhost:8080/a/tes.php?q=
every i refresh page with empty query, the data in txt was removed? i use this `for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++){ 
    unset($myFile[$i]);
}` how to dont remove if query was empty?

Comment: I think the better to do is not save if query is empty. The if(!empty($_GET["Q"])){ should not allow the edition in the txt file.

Comment: you could put some echo "here 1", "here 2" ... in your line code to understand where the php are cleaning the file ...